# How to add onclick event of dynamically added buttons

Tags: asp.net, aspbutton

How to add **`OnClick`** event of dynamically added buttons in asp.net. I have added buttons dynamically and now I want to create an clickevent for those buttons.

```
 if (dtTasks.Rows[j]["EmpID"].Equals(dtEmployees.Rows[i]["EmpID"]))
 {
       TableRow r = new TableRow();
       TableCell[] cells =  new TableCell();
       Button btn = new Button();
       btn.ID = "btn" + dtTasks.Rows[j]["TaskID"].ToString();
       btn.Text = "Add Comment";
       btn.OnClientClick = "Click";
       cells.Controls.Add(btn);
 }
```

Comment: what you want server side event or client side event ????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the button's `Click` handler like this.

```
 btn.Click += new EventHandler(btnClick);
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to add the client side click event as:

```
btn.Attributes.Add("OnClick","return clientClick(this);");
```

where this will hold the button for your manipulation, if you don't need it, than don't pass it.

Comment: if you need to have a server side event than you can follow the answer provided by Sachin.